# Are Google Docs Properties saved in document versions?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am building an Add-on for Google Docs using Google Apps Script, and that add-on saves some data in the [Document Properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties). I need to be able to roll back the document, and therefore probably use the Google Versions. My question is, if I save a version, are the document properties saved for that version or are they always the most recent ones?

Comment: This is something that it's easy to figure by yourself. If you need help on this, please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: It is indeed, just wanted to check if anyone already checked that, but as it doesn't seem like it I will check it myself and answer my question here. So this question is half a question and half a post to save some time for other people who encounter this question.

Comment: So you are saying that you found Document Properties from the PropertiesService inside of a documents revision history?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understood you correctly, but if I did then no, I'm saying that the revision history allows me to "Restore this version" for an old version, and then the question (which I will test later) is whether the restored version restores the properties as well.

Comment: You want to know whether the Document Property is also back when the revision of Google Document is back. If my understanding is correct, about this situation, when I tested it, the Document Property is not changed, and the latest values of Document Property are returned, while the Document is back. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: You understood me correctly, and that answers my question, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Tanaike, [Document properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getDocumentProperties()) are not rolled back whenever an older version is restored, they remain unchanged.

This makes sense, since properties from [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties) are stored in the script, not in the document. Hence, they *live* outside document versions, so to speak.